# Gmail email markup not working with invoices and script.google.com

Tags: gmail, google-schemas

I'm testing this markup https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/invoice on https://script.google.com/, so I discard all the SPF problems.

This is the JS:

```
function testSchemas() {
  var htmlBody = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('mail_template').getContent();

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),
    subject: 'Test Email markup - ' + new Date(),
    htmlBody: htmlBody,
  });
}
```

And this is the HTML

```
<html>
  <head>

<script type='application/ld+json'>
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Invoice",
  "accountId": "123-456-789",
  "minimumPaymentDue": {
    "@type": "PriceSpecification",
    "price": "$70.00"
  },
  "paymentDue": "2015-11-22T08:00:00+00:00",
  "paymentStatus": "PaymentAutomaticallyApplied",
  "provider": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "Mountain View Utilities"
  },
  "totalPaymentDue": {
    "@type": "PriceSpecification",
    "price": "$70.00"
  }
}
</script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      This a test for a Go-To action in Gmail.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

As you may see, the code should be fine. Ok, I execute the code and I receive this (please, add "h" at beggining, stackoverflow dont let me add more than 2 links):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bg8S2.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ituM0.png

What I'm doing wrong? one-click actions on http://gmail-actions.appspot.com/ works fine, but I can't get working invoices.

Comment: Well, you can only test your gmail schemas by sending emails to yourself. All emails where the sender and the recipient are the same account ignore the registration requirements and can be used for self-testing. Note that DKIM or SPF authentication is still required for self-testing.

Make sure that you registered with Google before you send emails to other users properly. You can find it in this [link](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google). 

For more information, check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30680493) if it can help you.

Comment: Thanks @Kendi, as you may see on the images, the "from" it's "yo" in spanish, "me" in english. On the other picture I had to strike the address, as it was my address sending to my address for self-testing. I copy-pasted the exactly same script you can see [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/invoice). I tried again now with the same script, and on the [following image](https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/qYlk1wYBT.png), you can see I have a DKIM and SPF authentication too, so I really don't know what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: @punchi Invoice schemas will only integrate with Inbox (http://inbox.google.com). Could you log into Inbox and see if your emails worked correctly there?

Comment: @Franco as you said, works only on google inbox, thanks (already had an answer with that info, but was deleted)